# invoking gradle as part of bash script terminates that script

Tags: bash, gradle

Following script gets terminated after first invocation of `gradlew`. Why is that?

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

find $PWD -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read d; do
  cd $d
  echo "cd" $d
  if [ -e "pom.xml" ]; then
    echo $d " contains pom.xml"
    mvn clean
    echo "cleaned" $d
  fi
  if [ -e "gradlew" ]; then
    echo $d " contains gradlew"
    ./gradlew -q clean
    echo "cleaned" $d
  fi
done
```

Output:

```
$ ./clean-all 
cd /home/user/code
cd /home/user/code/smstest
/home/user/code/smstest  contains gradlew
cleaned /home/bpiech/code/smstest
```

It works for every maven project if I comment gradle invocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing while loop to for-in loop fixed my problem. Still, it would be nice to know why it works this way.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

for d in $(find $PWD -maxdepth 1 -type d); do
  cd $d
  echo "cd" $d
  if [ -e "pom.xml" ]; then
    echo $d "contains pom.xml"
    mvn clean
    echo "cleaned" $d
  fi
  if [ -e "gradlew" ]; then
    echo $d "contains gradlew"
    ./gradlew clean
    echo "cleaned" $d
  fi
done
```

Comment: with the pipe-to-while everything in the while loop sees the output of find. I suspect the gradlew file ate the stdin.  but I am pointing fingers with only circumstantial evidence.

Comment: @Jasen You're right https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60499226/gradle-breaks-out-of-bash-for-loop