# Gradle Breaks out of Bash for loop

Tags: java, bash, git, gradle

I have a version history that I'm trying to run a gradle build on and in my bash script I have

```sh
while read -r version
do
    git checkout $version
    gradle clean
    gradle javadoc
    ...
done < version-history.log
```

which is trying to get the documentation for every tagged release of my code. The problem is that gradle runs a build once and then breaks out of the for loop. I tried encapsulating it in a function call, but it still manages to break out of the loop. Is this behavior intentional? How can I prevent it from doing this? My gradle version is

```sh
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-03-01 17:25:20 UTC
Revision:     <unknown>

Kotlin:       1.3.61
Groovy:       2.5.8
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          13.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 13.0.2+8)
OS:           Linux 5.5.6-arch1-1 amd64
```

Comment: it's more likely gradle returns a non-zero error code which breaks the loop.

Comment: I just verified, it's returning 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gradle consumes the input for some reason, which is what causes this behavior. Appending `</dev/null` to the gradle call seems to fix the problem, try

```
while read -r version; do
  git checkout $version
  gradle clean </dev/null
done <version-history.log
```